# new points added into the chart not visible at the last of the chart highstock

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using `highstock` candlestick chart into my angular application. Here's the options of my stock chart.

```
rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      colors: Global.colors,
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        crosshair: true
      },
      yAxis: [
        {
          opposite: true,
          labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 5
          },
          height: '60%',
          lineWidth: 2,
          resize: {
            enabled: true
          },
        }, {
          labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
          },
          top: '65%',
          height: '35%',
          offset: 0,
          lineWidth: 2
        }],
      tooltip: {
        split: false,
        shared: true,
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
      }
```

In this if you observe, I have disabled `rangeSelector`, `navigator`and `scrollbar`. Here I am getting values from the server and setting the values as part of series in the chart.

```
stockChart.addSeries({
  type:'candlestick',
  name:this.seriesName,
  data:this.seriesData
});
```

Now, in this. Whenever I have to add a point which is I am receiving through web socket. I need to remove the first value from the data array and then add a new value. In short shift and push.

```
updateChart(newValue){
   this.seriesData.shift();
   this.seriesData.push(newValue);
   this.stockChart.series[0].setData([]);
   this.stockChart.series[0].setData(this.seriesData);
}
```

Whenever this method is executed, a new point is added into the `seriesData` array and also applied as series data to the chart but until and unless I don't drag it to the left side, the tick is not visible. Also the chart doesn't seems like updated. I have tried the same with `series[0].addPoint(newValue,true,true)` to add a point and shift but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Could you supply some more details on why `addPoint` did not work. Error messages, what happened? A [MCVE] would go a long way to getting you help faster.

Comment: when I have used `series[0].addPoint(newValue,true,true)`. This give me no error, worked same as what I did with `seriesData` array which is my component variable but `addPoint()` also added some unusual point when I dragged it to the left.

Comment: My problem is, when I added a point. Its added into my component variable and I also have set it as series data property. New value should be shown at the last of the chart viewport but to see the new value I need to drag the chart points to the left.

Comment: Are you using `highchart-angular` official wrapper in your app? Check this demo where points are updated properly in an angular app: https://codesandbox.io/s/k0j6x08l3. Could you prepare an online demo of your app? Perhaps some of your options are set incorrectly.